# $\frac{1}{n}/\frac{1}{n^2}$ understanding

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

The limit of $\frac{1}{n}/\frac{1}{n^2}$ when $n \rightarrow +\infty$ is $+\infty$.

By calculation this is an obvious result, yet I don't understand why this is true. 
$1/n$ will never reached the value $0$ because the équation $1/n=0$ hasn't any solutions. It's exactly the same for $1/n^2$.
Moreover the difference $1/n-1/n^2=0$ when $n \rightarrow +\infty$. 
So why $\frac{1}{n}/\frac{1}{n^2} \ne 1$ when $n\rightarrow +\infty$.

Comment: Please don't post multiple questions at once.

Comment: $\frac{1}{n}/\frac{1}{n^2}=n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} n=\infty$

Comment: These questions are directly related but I've edited.

Comment: @Cornman what you've said doesn't help at all as I said in my post.

Comment: What does the fact that $1/n\not =0$ for all $n$ have to do with the limit?

Comment: although initially counterintuitive, it can happen that two sequences of numbers get arbitrarily close, while the number of times the one fits in the other gets arbitrarily small. The problem lies with the fact that $\frac{a}{b}$ being close to $1$ is by no means equivalent to $a-b$ being small! The first statement says something like '$b$ fits in $a$ almost once' while the second says the '$a$ and $b$ lie very close to eachother (absolutely speaking)'. So for example, $\frac{n-1}{n}$ gets closer and closer to one, while $n-1-n=-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we have limits of the type $$\frac00$$
then there is a difference between $0.000001$ and $0.00000000001$ which is $$\frac{0.000001}{0.00000000001}=100000$$
while $$\frac{2.000001}{2.00000000001}=1.0000005$$
Intuitively this is because when you have $\frac00$ then you have something small divided by something also small which can be anything while if you have $\frac ll$ then you have something which is $l$ and something small divided by $l$ and something small it always goes to $1$ and something small.

You should try to use the definition of limits to prove such a statement rigorously.

Answer (score 3):

It's all about the speed of convergence. Clearly $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=0$, but $\frac{1}{n^2}$ tends to zero faster than $\frac{1}{n}$.

Thus when we consider the ratio $\frac{1}{n}/\frac{1}{n^2}$ the denominator will then to zero faster than the nominator. Indeed, just pick a large value for $n$ and compare: $n=10$ yields $\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{10}$ and $\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{1}{100}$.

In many such cases you can use l'Hopitals rule, and if you think about it, all this rule does is compare the speed of convergences of the nominator to that of the denominator.

Comment: Ok but why when we have something of the form $l/l$ we ignore the speed of convergence ?

Comment: We don't ignore it, they have the same speed, so they cancel each other.

Answer (score 1):

The wordy answer is that $1/n^2$ reaches $0$ faster than $1/n$ reaches $0$ as $n\to\infty$, so you have $(\text{something close to }0)/(\text{something even closer to }0)$. However, a bit of algebra gives

$\displaystyle{\frac{1/n}{1/n^2}=\frac{n^2}{n^2}\times\frac{1/n}{1/n^2}=n}$ ,

which very clearly $\to\infty$ as $n\to 0$.

Regarding the more general question of $0/0$ limits, lets take three examples:

$\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to0}\frac{n}{n^2}=\lim_{n\to0}\frac{1}{n}=\infty}$

$\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to0}\frac{n^2}{n}=\lim_{n\to0}n=0}$

$\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to0}\frac{5n}{n}=\lim_{n\to0}5=5}$

These are all $0/0$ limits.

I know I haven't answered all your points, but I hope what's here can help.

Comment: Thank you ! but why we ignore the speed of convergence when we have something of the form $l/l$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to convince you it is true. Take a large pie, and divide it in 4 equal pieces. Then one piece fits exactly twice in half the pie, that is 
$$\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{2^2}}=2.$$
More generally, if we divide the pie in $n^2$ equal pieces, and we join $n$ groups of $n$ of these pieces together, by pasting where we have cut, we obviously have divided the pie in $n$ equal pieces! That is, any of the small pieces (that fit $n^2$ times in the pie) fit $n$ times in any of the big pieces (which fit $n$ times in the pie). So 
$$\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n^2}}=n.$$
So as $n$ becomes arbitrarily large, this fraction gets arbitrarily large.

Answer (score -1):

Adding to EdMo38, take examples of n getting smaller and smaller, eg. n=1 : lim=1, n=0.1 : lim=10, n=0.01 : lim=100, n=0.001 : lim=1000, etc.